# Pythonic Multithreading of "jobs"

Tags: python, asynchronous, async-await, python-3.6

I have an application that needs to make a set 30-40 API calls, each of which kick off query "jobs" that will need polled for status, and then retrieved from the API.  Each job will take an unknown amount of time -anywhere from immediate to 3-4 minutes.

This seems like a great place to apply a multithreading model wherein I "dispatch" these jobs and then wait for all of them to be completed before processing the results.  I am confused by all the options available for this in Python, and it's unclear to me whether I should use `concurrent.futures` or `asyncio` or `greenlets`.

How do I evaluate the options and make a choice that results in readable, Pythonic code?  Which of these libraries is the most prevalent and reusable(in other words, which one is a good investment for my time)? 
Which is best suited for my task?

Any advice or guidance on how to translate my problem into Python 3.6+ would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not really sure what you are asking. However, multiprocessing is really easy with Python and if you simply need to trigger jobs, then the following might help:

```
import multiprocessing as mp

def print_index(x):
    print(x)

jobs = []
for i in range(3):  
    p = mp.Process(target=print_index, args=(i,))
    jobs.append(p)
    p.start()

for job in jobs: #wait for the 3 jobs to finish...
    job.join()
```

You can find out more about multiprocessing via the documentation: https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html

Comment: Thanks!  I'm mostly just looking for help understand the "best" or most prevalent way to accomplish multithreading or multiprocessing.  There's a wide range of tools available for this and it's unclear which ones are still relevant since the addition of `asyncio` to the standard library around 3.5!

Comment: Don't use asyncio. It's not worth the extra time to understand it. Also, I would recommend threads here as you're not cpu bound.

Comment: Yes, multithreading is more suitable. Not sure why I had MP on the mind.